# manipulating img src with regex -php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How would I replace this:

```
http://example.com/myfolder/files/year/month/imagename-widthxheight.imageextension
```

to this:

```
http://example.com/myfolder/files/year/month/imagename-300x300.imageextension
```

any help?

Comment: This part "widthxheight" is not text, but the "old" resolution like 123x456, right?

Comment: yes. it is variable. users upload different sizes of pics. system produces 300x300 thumbs. resizes & crops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this

```
// if your src has widthxheight are specified literally like that you may try
echo preg_replace("/\W{0,1}(width).*(height)/i","-300x300","http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/files/year/month/imagename-widthxheight.imageextension");
// if your src has widthxheight are specified in int val you may try     
echo preg_replace("/\W{0,1}(\d{1,7}).*(\d{1,7})/i","-300x300","http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/files/year/month/imagename-123x456.imageextension");
```

actual value of -300x300 will vary on your actual requirement. So I think its best to pass on these values through variables.

Comment: let me show some real content: `<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-6" src="http://www.mysite.com/bela/files/2012/02/turinhorse-620x413.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="413" />

A Torinói ló - The Turin Horse - Torino atı, Tarr'ın 2011 yapımı filmi. <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1316540/">IMDB sayfası burada.</a>`

Comment: If you want to operate on full image tag then you can use this too

echo preg_replace("/((\d{1,7})x(\d{1,7})\.)/","300x300.",'<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-6" src="http://www.mysite.com/bela/files/2012/02/turinhorse-620x413.jpg" alt="" width="620" height="413" /> A Torinói ló - The Turin Horse - Torino atı, Tarr'ın 2011 yapımı filmi.');

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$new_img = preg_replace("~([^/]+)-widthxheight(\.[^.]+)$~i","$1-300x300$2", 
"http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/files/year/month/imagename-widthxheight.imageextension");
```